# Passing a List to View in Play Framework

Tags: list, playframework, mongodb-java

So, I'm using the Play Framework in conjunction with MongoDB. I'm attempting to pass a List to my view to loop through and display the rows.

Controller:

```
public static Result find() {
    List<DBObject> results = MongoController.find(MongoController.getLocalConnection("test"), "jobs");
    if (results == null) { 
        redirect("/");
    }
    return ok(find_job.render(results));
}
```

The MongoController called above uses the following function (functioning - tried and tested):

```
public static List<DBObject> find(DB database, String collectionName) {
    DBCursor cursor = database.getCollection(collectionName).find();

    List<DBObject> items = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        items.add(cursor.next());
    }

    return items;
}
```

View:

```
@(results : List[DBObject])
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Compilation error:

Not found: type DBObject
```

Does anybody have any pointers please? I apologise - I'm new to this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twirl templates don't work quite the same way when importing things into the local namespace. By default only the `models` package, and a few other Play packages are imported into the view namespace. Imports made afterward are not used for the template parameters.

You need to either use the fully-qualified package name:

```
@(results: List[com.mongodb.DBObject])
```

Or you can add to the `templateImports` key in `build.sbt`. i.e., you'd drop this line into your `build.sbt` file:

```
TwirlKeys.templateImports += "com.mongodb.DBObject"
```

This will add the previous import to all compiled templates. Note that it's for Play 2.3.x. If using 2.2.x, then you'd use the following instead:

```
templatesImport += "com.mongodb.DBObject"
```

Comment: Thanks - this was a big help. So when I iterate through the rows within the view, is there any way to address the specific fields for formatting? I.e. @for(result <- results) {
  <tr>
   <td>@result.name</td>
   <td>@result.address</td>
  </tr>
 }